# what's the best way in clojure to swap! an atom if it's nil?

Tags: clojure

Say I have a atom initially set to 0.
I would like to initialize it only if it is not previously initialized,

What I have now:

```
(swap! atom #(if % % (initialize)))
```

However, this just doesn't look idiomatic to me.

There must be a more readable way right?

Comment: `0` is truthy in clojure so this will never call `initialize`. Are you sure you don't set it to `nil` initially?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Often you can use `fnil` to avoid needing to do the initialization check in the first place. For instance `(swap! counts update word (fnil inc 0))` is saying increment the value at key word in counts, but if there is no value there use 0.

Comment: i would also add an op's case: `(swap! a (fnil identity (initialize)))`

Comment: then `(initialize)` must be a pure function.